# PYTHONANYWHERE ... i've started to get a "403 FORBIDDEN" error when trying to access /admin/default/

Tags: pythonanywhere

thanks in advance for the help.

I need to access one of my apps admin area (I do this every day as I am constantly updating the code) but this morning I got the following error when trying to access "https://www.tenissocial.pt/admin/default" ..

"403 FORBIDDEN"

Any ideas? Many thanks, Pedro

. http://www.tenissocial.pt/ is working fine

. I've made no changes to the app or anywhere within the setup of my pythonanywhere services

. I've got other 2 apps/web services that are within the same pythonanywhere account still working fine. ie, I can access via https://.../default/admin/

. the app code is inside /web2py2 directory

Comment: maybe it had to to do http/https and your ssl cert

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to "solve" the issue by deleting the web app; creating a new one; recreating the app by using the backed-up package from a few days ago; adding missing data by hand; and changing the CNAME on my host....

A bit of a pain, but it worked.... I still don't know what caused the problem, but all is now good. 
Thanks to all. 
Kind regards,
Pedro